# Devise with User model and STI, wrong controller on registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I had User model for a while that worked with devise, now I have to add a new model to the app, called Profile, and as it has almost the same attributes as User I decided to inherit Profile from User.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

**profile**

```
class Profile < User
  ...
end
```

updated **routes** to work with devise:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_up => "becometutor"},
                 :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }

  devise_for :profiles, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_up => "brand_profile"}, 
                 :controllers => { :registrations => "profiles/registrations" }
```

**rake routes**

```
user_registration POST         /                         users/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET      /becometutor(.:format)    users/registrations#new
profile_registration POST      /                         profiles/registrations#create
new_profile_registration GET   /brand_profile(.:format)  profiles/registrations#new
```

**Problem**

When I open `new_profile_registration` logs shows:

```
Processing by Profiles::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
```

when I click submit on form that should create a profile, logs shows:

```
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "profile"=>{"name"=>"", "phone"=>"", "owner_name"=>"", "owner_phone_number"=>""
```

**Question**

why create action points to `Users::RegistrationController`, instead of `Profiles::RegistrationController` ?

Thank you.

---

**Fix** - set path to be different for each resource

```
  devise_for :users, :path => 'tutors', :path_names => {:sign_up => "becometutor"},
                 :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }

  devise_for :profiles, :path => 'profiles', :path_names => { :sign_up => "brand_profile"}, 
                 :controllers => { :registrations => "profiles/registrations" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 routes with the same url, `user_registration POST /` and `profile_registration POST /`, so Rails looks for the first, and it's point to `users/registrations#create`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i guess it is due  `routes` . If you put `profile` route  above `user` route  , it might work.
You might be passing `@user` simply to the `form_for` and it is picking `user` `create` path as it comes first.

Comment: the form is the default one from devise that uses `resource` as object: `form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)`. Artem answer fixed my issue, thank you.